# JQuery timing events not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, timing

I am having issues with my timing events in [my simon memory game](http://codepen.io/furball/pen/egGPeZ?editors=0010) that I have created.

I've tried using setTimeout but I don't know which events to time and how much time to set so that theyre distinguishable.

```
$('#play').click(function(){
    console.log('start');
    generate();
    setTimeout(game,1000);
    levelUp();
});
```

Please refer to my codepen link above

Additional code:

```
function generate (){
 var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*4 +1);
 compArr.push(randomNum);
 console.log('compArr:'+compArr);
}

function game () {
 for (var i =0;i<compArr.length;i++){
  console.log('iterate:'+compArr[i]); 
  switch (compArr[i]) {
   case 1:
   one();
   break;
   case 2:
   two();
   break;                
   case 3:
   three();
   break;         
   case 4:
   four();
   break;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow makes you include code and not just a link to code pen because it makes you focus your question.  Cut your problem down to a manageable size, post that code *here*, and then we can help you out.

Comment: ive added aditional code below as an answer

Comment: I've edited your code into the question; it would be nice to delete your answer (answers are supposed to just be answers).  In the future, you can use the edit link to do that as well.  It's still not clear from this page what you're trying to do.  Making people go to your codepen to figure it out will severely cut down on the number and quality of answers you will receive.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the level you're in you're going to have "n + level"  colors you have to click.

you need to split up your "game" code into starting a new round and sounding /showing the desired tiles.

seems like simplest way to do this is just looping over the "tile array"  and waiting "n" (milli) seconds to show the next required option.

Comment: please refer to the code i posted below as an answer

Comment: thats how im looping through the array

Answer (score 0):

```
function generate (){
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*4 +1);
  compArr.push(randomNum);
  console.log('compArr:' + compArr); 
}

function game () {
  for (var i =0;i<compArr.length;i++){
    console.log('iterate:' + compArr[i]); 
    switch (compArr[i]) {
      case 1:
        one();
        break;
      case 2:
        two();
        break;                
      case 3:
        three();
        break;         
      case 4:
        four();
        break;                     
    } 
  }
}
```